# Continued Challenge : Serializing Math for Projecting to C# and Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, serialization

I have asked a few questions related to this, but from different angles. I am trying yet again another approach.

The design in question relates to a system in which the client is able to create various **entities** in the system, and as needed build mathematical formulas to tether those entities together in some meaningful way. This is an important distinction because these entities do not exist at design time.

A client might then create a few entities. a, b, c, n, r and x.
So then, a client might say **"I need a to equal [ b + c ]( n * r ) + [ x ]"**.

a, b, c, n, r and x all make sense to the client. They have names and values in the context of what the client is viewing. But to the underlying system, they did not exist at design time - so this formula does not exist.

So then, is there any way to take this equation and serialize it in such a way that it can be deserialized and executed against a given list of variables? I am using C#, ASP.NET MVC, RavenDB, and JavaScript.

The equations will be defined by the administrator of the software, and are relative to each individual user. They need to be stored in the database so that they can be executed server side, and also client side.

Comment: if I understand correctly the hardest part is not serialization but finding a way to compute the mathematical statement represented by your string

Comment: Yes. This would be an accurate assessment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a formula parser for mathematical expressions.

On server side, you can use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/), and although you can use JavaScripts [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function on client side, in order to have an identical interpretation of input strings, you should consider using a webservice called from Javascript (or jquery) that simply parses a client formula on the server.

BTW, NCalc can even parse customised expressions.

Comment: So I could have "x + y + (n * r)" in my database, and then a list of where x, y, n, and r would be found, have it unwrap x, y, n, and r, plug them in, and perform the calculation on execution?

Comment: Watch out for mathematical precision though and JavaScript - it's notoriously problematic.

Comment: Yeah, I do not think it will be possible to come up with a solution that will work across both C# and JavaScript. I am going to take the advice about using a service like controller to handle the calculations server side, and then return them to JS via ajax.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a grammar (a mini-language that represents what you need to represent), save the expression as text in raven, write a parser and a code generator for each language in question.

A parser takes the expression and converts it into an "abstract syntax tree".

The code generator takes the "abstract syntax tree" and converts it into natively executable code.  You will need a separate generator for C# and for JavaScript depending on where you are executing the expression.

**At a high level, you can achieve this by embedding a scripting language into .Net such as IronPython**.  You would probably be better off doing this as the work above is non-trivial.

If you want to do it the hard way, buy these and get reading:

- http://www.amazon.co.uk/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0321491696
- http://www.amazon.co.uk/Structure-Interpretation-Computer-Electrical-Engineering/dp/0262510871

I've written a number of "mini-languages" over the years and they are not trivial to design.

Comment: Can I bother you to elaborate on the idea of embedding a scripting language? I am unfamiliar with doing this.

Comment: Of course.  There's an example here on how to embed and utilise a scripting language at the following link.  It describes it in a mathematical context as well: http://reflectivecode.com/2008/10/embedding-ironpython

Comment: Thank you for this, it will be immensely helpful. I am going to try NCalc first, but a full scripting embedding is my next venue if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Good luck :)  If you need any help, feel free to post again on this question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is still not clear what exactly you mean, but depending on what is going on at the client, you will have to parse it either there or on the server.  If client does fancy things with the formula, parse it on the client and send it back to the server as a parsed expression tree.  If not, send it to the server as a string and parse it there.

Comment: Yes, but I am asking if anyone knows of a way to do said parsing. And it needs to be saved to the database. But since formulas are sensitive to the context they run in, it cannot be stored with hard-coded values.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling this is exactly what [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/) was created for.

Try using [suim](http://suim.jp/) to serialize the expression as a MathML document before sending it to the server and you'd de-serialize on the server using a C# MathML library (I can't name any).

Comment: I actually looked at MathML, but I got the impression it was more for just displaying the formulas, rather than actually calculating them.